# TLS handshake cryptography AES key query

Tags: aes, tls

I am working on a IoT project where I am trying to perform manual handshake (SSL) for certificates and sending data to the server securely using HTTPS POST method.

RSA is used for sending Pre-master Secret from client to the server.

I want to know how client or server calculate AES key from:

1. Pre master secret (32 bytes)
2. Client random (32 bytes)
3. Server random (32 bytes)

there are few posts which claims that it is being created by using

```
PRF(pre-master,client.random,server.random);
```

I wish C language works in this, but I dont have the PRF function body.

Does anyone have a code for the PRF, or is there any onther way for creating AES key at client side?

Also I would like to know the real use of SHA1/256 in TLS handshake.

Justification with example would be a real help.

---

I know realise that we ourselves won't derive AES algorithm keys.
But to work with AES one must have MasterKey, which can be derived from ( pre Master, client random and server random ) in TLS 1.3.

So I am stuck on the process of getting masterKey from the above parameters.
And even https://tls.ulfheim.net doesn't document the key derivation process using the pre-master secret and the two `hello`s for TLS 1.2 (or TLS 1.3).

Comment: Writing an SSL/TLS implementation on your own can be troublesome and error-prone. One of our well-reputed member created [BearSSL](https://bearssl.org/) which can target lightweight environments you should check out. After that, just find a good HTTP library to go with it, or you can limit your self to the few actually needed headers and methods.

Comment: @DannyNiu  yes I know it could be little troublesome,but as my project requirement is customized thus I am going for it.     I have successfully extracted other data from server just need the actual function which is being used by clients like chrome or other devices for generating AES key.    Thank you.

Comment: hi @DannyNiu can you help me with AES key generation function used at client side..? i will be so thankful.

Comment: @VaibhavTayade If you want an explanation of the different parts of a TLS handshake, you might find https://tls.ulfheim.net/ interesting.  (Not mine; it's just a great reference.)

Comment: For RSA keyexchange the premaster is 48 bytes, like the master for all keyexchanges. Note the main issue with security software is that testing it works functionally does _nothing_ to establish its security. You may well get this to 'work' but it almost certainly won't be secure, which means if your 'project' is actually used by anybody there's a very good chance you will cause them serious harm.

Answer (score 1):

Everything is defined in the RFC that specifies the protocol. For example, if you're using TLS 1.2, then see [section 5 of RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#section-5): `PRF` is defined using `P_<hash>`, where `hash` depends on the suite negotiated in the handshake; `P_<hash>` in turn is defined using HMAC.

Comment: Note you don't derive _one_ AES (or other cipher) key, for <=1.2 you derive one master secret and then multiple working keys (at least 2, often 4 or 6); see sections 8.1 and 6.3 in addition to 6. For 1.3 it is substantially different and a good bit more complicated, plus the document is reorganized.

Comment: [This is the relevant section for TLS 1.3](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8446#section-7.1)